# Node specific CPU usage limit in Docker swarm?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, cpu-usage, docker-swarm

I want to set the node specific CPU usage limit in Docker swarm environment.
I know we can set the CPU usage limit using yaml file for used to deploy service on all nodes  like

```
 resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '0.50'
```

However this will set CPU usage limit on all nodes. What if I wanted to set different CPU limit for each node.
How to set node specific cpu limit value?

Comment: you want to set the cpu limit for whole node? isnt it better to set it per service?

Comment: @MazelTov I have to launch a service on all the nodes but with different CPU limit for service on different node.